# C++で挿入ソートを実装する際、一時変数の役目が分からない

Tags: c++, アルゴリズム

挿入ソートについて学習しており、一つ疑問があるのですが、なぜ `temp` の変数を使わなけばならないのでしょうか？

[挿入ソート | Programming Place Plus アルゴリズムとデータ構造編](https://programming-place.net/ppp/contents/algorithm/sort/004.html)

**正しい挙動のコード:**

```
　　int arry[] = {5,2,8,3,1};

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
　　　　int temp = arry[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) and (arry[j] > temp))
        {
            arry[j + 1] = arry[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arry[j + 1] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arry[i];
    }
```

下記のように `temp` 変数を使わずそのまま `while` の条件文で配列にアクセスしようとすると、正しい挙動を確認することが出来ません。
是非ご教授お願い致します。

**tempを使わないコード:**

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
　　    //int temp = arry[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) and (arry[j] > arry[i]))
        {
            arry[j + 1] = arry[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arry[j + 1] = arry[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

自分で解答がわかりました。

変数に一時退避しておかないと、上書きされてしまうからでした。